# How to fulfill submission form with data upload using Selenium?

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver

I'm trying to write an autocomplete function that selects the correct buttons, loads a file, and runs the program. But for now, it opens my desktop to select a file (and should fill it in automatically), and even after I manually select the correct file, the program closes the browser immediately.

Here is my code:

```
 


driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=Service(ChromeDriverManager().install()))

driver.get("https://meme-suite.org/meme/tools/xstreme")
k = Select(driver.find_element(By.NAME, "sequences_source"))
k.select_by_value('file')
uploadname1= EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, '//\*\[@id="sequences"\]/div\[1\]/span\[1\]'))

WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(uploadname1).click() # This opens the windows file selector

pyautogui.write("file.FASTA")
pyautogui.press('return')

l = Select(driver.find_element(By.NAME, "motifs_source"))
l.select_by_value('26')
start_search = driver.find_element(By.NAME, "search")
start_search.click()\`
```

Comment: _the program closes the browser immediately_: Do you see any error?

Comment: try to add `time.sleep(3)` before and after the line `pyautogui.write("file.FASTA")`

Comment: Also, not sure why you put `/` in the xpath, it should be `//*[@id="sequences"]/div[1]/span[1]`